# "The method 'SplashScreen' isn't defined for the type 'MyApp'.". I have tried a lot of things and nothing. Any solution?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, mobile

main.dart:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart' show BuildContext, Colors, MaterialApp, StatelessWidget, ThemeData, VisualDensity, Widget, runApp;

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        // Application name
        title: 'UranteX',
        theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.red,
          visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
        ),
        home: SplashScreen());
  }
```

splashScreen.dart(2nd page)

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart' show BuildContext, Center, Column, Container, CrossAxisAlignment, Image, MainAxisAlignment, Scaffold, SizedBox, State, StatefulWidget, Widget;

class SplashScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SplashScreenState createState() => _SplashScreenState();
}

class _SplashScreenState extends State<SplashScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        height: double.infinity,
        width: double.infinity,
        child: Center(
          child: Column(crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center, mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center, children: [
            SizedBox(
              height: 300.0,
              child: Image.asset('Images/logo.png'),
            )
          ]),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

///The code isn't working and its saying that"The method 'SplashScreen' isn't defined for the type 'MyApp'". I know the solution probably is on the "Container" but I can't solve it.

Comment: add this code in `main.dart` `import splashScreen,dart`

Comment: I did it and still not working. I've also tried to import the main.dart to the splashScreen.dart file, but I'm getting the same error

Answer (score 0):

Solution: You have to import splashScreen.dart file into your main.dart
Reason of problem: You are calling SplashScreen class which is in another file so how main.dart file will get to know that what is SplashScreen there So you need to import splashscreen.dart file so that main.dart will know that SplashScreen is a class from splashScreen.dart file.

If you still have doubt then you can ask
if you satisfied then give this answer an upvote so that more will learn this.

Comment: I've tried it too and still not working. Tried to import the 2 files. Any other solution?

Comment: change name of your 2nd page and don't use camel case while giving name to files use underscore just like this > splash_screen.dart

Comment: you saved my life now with one other code I'm developing with this last comment. Many thanks bro. All the best to you and happy coding!